# Azure Table Storage return query results

Tags: javascript, azure, callback, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to create an Azure Function that will take take in parameter(s) and return a value stored in an Azure Table. I believe the issue I'm having has more to do with javascript than it does with the Azure Table SDK.

How are you supposed to return the value from the query via http response? I have attached a copy of the code and it should explain where I'm confused. My main confusion is due to the fact that I'm able to call `context.log()` but unable to call `context.res{}` from the function in the query method.

I know that scope has something to do with it but I am not an expert when it comes to javascript and nested functions. Some guidance or example would be appreciated

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('Some Function');
    var hostUri = 'https://*******.table.core.windows.net'
    var sasToken = 'abc123'

    if (req.query.value) {
        var tableService = azure.createTableServiceWithSas(hostUri, sasToken)
        var nothing =  tableService.retrieveEntity('Table', 'Partition', 'Row', function(error, result, response) {
            if (!error) {
                context.log('I am able to send data to the logs here')         
                context.res = {
                    status: 200,
                    body: "This is what I am tring to return -> " + JSON.stringify(result) 
                };       
            }
        })
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: "I'm able to get a response here"
        };  
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Somthing went wrong..."
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution first:

```
if (req.query.value) {
    var tableService = azure.createTableServiceWithSas(hostUri, sasToken)
     tableService.retrieveEntity('Table', 'Partition', 'Row', function(error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            context.log('I am able to send data to the logs here')         
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: "This is what I am tring to return -> " + JSON.stringify(result) 
            }; 
        }
        else{
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: error
            };
        }
        context.done(); 
    })

}
else {
    context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: "Value is empty"
    };
    context.done();
}
```

Explanation:

Let's mark the context.res in order as c1 and c2 to avoid redundant.

You are caught by callback function. The callback `function(error, result, response){}` is not executed until entity is retrieved from remote sever(or error happens). This operation may take some time, the program continues executing while waiting for it to complete, this pattern is called `asynchronous`.

So your code snippet c1 in callback is not executed immediately but instead c2 is. Then `context.done();` runs before the entity retrieved(you see response message `I'm able to get a response here`), callback is hence never called.

Code relying on result of callback should be included in callback, so that it can execute exactly after callback is finished. Put `context.done();` in both callback and else segment to assure it won't run in advance.

Also one [blog about asynchronous-javascript](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee) for you to refer.